# Subclassing vs Extension vs Inner Class

Tags: swift

I'm interacting with the `Quizlet API` and I've been debating the best way to structure my code. The Quizlet API has multiple features such as viewing `Sets`, `Classes`, and other `User` info. I'm trying to create `APIClients` for this, but I've been struggling to find a better solution to modeling the clients or choose the best one out of these potential solutions.

**Solution 1:**
Create a `superclass` called `QuizletManager` and store the basic information like `clientID`, `access codes`, and related information which is useful throughout all the subclasses. Then I can create individual `subclasses` like `QuizletSet`, `QuizletClass`, etc to handle fetching the sets, classes, and related info. When I actually need to fetch the data, I'd probably never end up calling `QuizletManager`; however, I'd create new instances of the `QuizletSet` and related classes to do the networking.

**Solution 2:**
Create a `QuizletManager` superclass again with all of its related subclasses. However, this time I'd instantiate all of my subclasses related to Sets and all of that in the `QuizletManager` class and have methods within `QuizletManager` that call the subclasses when fetching information.
In this case, I would always call `QuizletManager` and `QuizletManager` would use the subclasses to actually fetch the information.

**Solution 3:**
Create a `QuizletManager` class and to make it more readable use extensions to add the functionality of fetching `Sets`, `Classes`, etc. The extensions would essentially contain functions that add the functionality of fetching `Sets` and related info.

**Solution 4:**
In this solution, I would have a class inside a class. Essentially, I'd just have something like this:

```
class QuizletManager {
    var clientID: String
    // Other related properties important for sets, classes, etc.
    class SetClient: APIClient {
        // Fetch related info for sets.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of your previous examples, you are coupled to a hierarchy or placing all API related calls as extensions on a single class. This could make your code less flexible and harder to maintain. One solution that may work for you is to use **dependency injection**.

Here is an example of how you could structure your code.

```
struct QuizletAPICredentials {
    var clientID: String
    var accessCodes: [String]
    //etc...
}

class QuizletSetClient {
    var credentials: QuizletAPICredentials

    init(credentials: QuizletAPICredentials) {
        self.credentials = credentials
    }

    func fetchSets( ... ) {
        //get data...
    }
}
```

I hope this helps! :-]

Comment: Ahh, I do like that approach. I'll see if there are any other suggestions/recommendations and then I'll accept your answer :)